# What is difference between Deployment Group and Deployment Pool?

Tags: azure-devops

When create Deployment Group in Azure DevOps, it automatically create a Deployment Pool for you.

However, from Organisation Setting -> Deployment Pool panel, you can create new deployment pool without create Deployment Group.

What is the relationship between Deployment Group and Deployment Pool ? Like can one deployment group being linked to multiple deployment pools for example?

Comment: However, the Deployment pools do not seem to be exposed by the API, like the documentation indicated...
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/pools/get%20agent%20pools?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Comment: But now (Azure DevOps 2019) Deployment Group does not create a Deployment Pool

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[This is a good blog to explain you the difference between deployment group and deployment pool.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2018/01/11/sharing-of-deployment-groups-across-projects/)

> The relationship between Deployment Pools and Deployment Groups is
>   similar to the relationship between [Agent Pools and Agent Queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/pools-queues?view=vsts). **A Deployment Pool exists at the account level and is the actual
>   container of the deployment agents (targets), whereas the Deployment
>   Group is a layer over it which makes these targets available to
>   release definitions in a project**
>
> Earlier, there was a one-one mapping between a Deployment Pool and a
>   Deployment Group i.e. each Deployment Group had a dedicated Deployment
>   Pool, and therefore there was no need to expose the Deployment Pool
>   concept to the user. But now that the deployment targets can be shared
>   across projects, we have exposed Deployment Pools in the product.
>
> A Deployment Pool can be shared with another project if the following
>   three conditions are true:
>
> 1. The user sharing the Deployment Pool is a “User” for the pool.
> 2. The user sharing the Deployment Pool has permissions to create a
>      Deployment Group in the project where it is being shared.
> 3. The project does not already have a Deployment Group backed by
>      the same pool.
>
> Note that the tags set on the deployment targets are project scoped
>   e.g. a deployment target might be tagged as “Web” in Project1 but
>   might be tagged as “MiddleTier” in Project2.

Comment: The blog post is a little out of date because the UI has changed (though the principles are still the same). The documentation has updated instructions - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azure-devops#share-a-deployment-group