# Azure DevOps Deployment Group

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-deploymentgroups

Would be great if someone can explain the best architecture for Azure DevOps Deployment Group

Let's assume I have 10 different applications. Source code segregated in different team collection and different team project.

For example:

1.Team Collection 1
1.1 Team Project 1
1.1.1 App 1
1.1.2 App 2
1.1.3 App 3

```
1.2 Team Project 2
   1.2.1 App 4
```

2. Team Collection 2
   2.1 Team Project 3
   2.1.1. App 5

Cont....

Also I have 3 dev environment front end servers which are common for all 10 applications.

**What would be the best approach to setup deployment groups in this my dev environment.**

1. How many deployment groups should I create
2. Do I need to specify the agent name while setup in target servers
3. Do I need to setup deployment pools

Comment: Thanks Leo, I'll go through the thread which you have mentioned. I'll get back soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How many deployment groups should I create

Itis depends on how many Team Collections you have. When you create a deployment group in a project, it will actually create a deployment pool at the **organization level**.

And we could [share a deployment group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azure-devops#share-a-deployment-group) and [add a deployment pool and group to another project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azure-devops#add-a-deployment-pool-and-group-to-another-project).

> Do I need to specify the agent name while setup in target servers

To configraure the deployment groups, I think we are not need to specify the agent name while setup in target servers.

> Do I need to setup deployment pools

I do not think you need to setup deployment pools. When we create Deployment Group in Azure DevOps, it automatically create a Deployment Pool for you.

You could check [the thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53271935/what-is-difference-between-deployment-group-and-deployment-pool) for some more details.